# Как оптимизировать картинки и скрипты на сайте wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, оптимизация, pagespeed-insights

Доброго времени суток wordpress разработчикам! Есть сайт [RIO](https://rio-design.com.ua/), который на pagespeed имеет параметр оптимизации 53/100 главной страницы, это очень мало, хотелось бы выйти хотя бы из красной зоны. Для этого, понятное дело, нужно исправить хотя бы важные ошибки (хотя Вы и сами все видите), это:

1. Оптимизировать изображения --> поставил плагин WP Smush, он как бы оптимизировал все изображения в медиафайлах, но осталась проблема, например в портфолио, там выводятся не миниатюры изображений, а родные уменьшенные картинки, а pagespeed хочет чтоб я их урезал, если я это сделаю, то и в самом портфолио внутри будет маленькая картинка, аналогичная ситуация и с блоком "последнее в блоге", тут же выводятся последние записи с блога, но картинки выводятся не в миниатюрах, а в родных картинках вставленных в статью и уменьшенных для показа в этом блоке, надеюсь Вы поняли, что я имел ввиду. Ах да, еще эта страница была создана с помощью visual composer, если это что-то поможет.
2. Что делать со скриптами и css, блокирующим отображение в верхней части страницы, ставил плагины типа: autoptimize или speed boost pack, или тот же W3 Total Cache и после включения некоторых параметров я получал + на pagespeed, но страница могла потерять слайдер или развалится вообще.

p.s. буду благодарен за любые советы и материалы в устранении данных проблем, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал решение для картинок. В function.php добавьте следующую функцию:

```
function aq_resize($url,$width,$height=null,$crop=null,$single=true){
    $up_info=wp_upload_dir();
    $up_dir=$up_info['basedir'];
    $up_url=$up_info['baseurl'];
    if (strpos($url,home_url()) === false){return false;}
    $rel_path = str_replace( $up_url, '', $url);
    $img_path = $up_dir . $rel_path;
    if (!file_exists($img_path) OR ! getimagesize($img_path)){return false;}
    $info = pathinfo($img_path);
    $ext = $info['extension'];
    list($orig_w,$orig_h) = getimagesize($img_path);
    $dims = image_resize_dimensions($orig_w, $orig_h, $width, $height, $crop);
    $dst_w = $dims['4'];
    $dst_h = $dims['5'];
    $suffix="{$dst_w}x{$dst_h}";
    $dstrel=str_replace('.'.$ext,'',$rel_path);
    $dest="{$up_dir}{$dstrel}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
    if($width >= $orig_w) {
        if(!$dst_h) :
            $img_url=$url;
            $dst_w=$orig_w;
            $dst_h=$orig_h;

        else :
            if(file_exists($dest) && getimagesize($dest)) {
                $img_url="{$up_url}{$dstrel}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
            }
            else {
                $resized=resize_image($img_path,$width,$height,$crop);
                $resized_rel=str_replace($up_dir,'',$resized);
                $img_url=$up_url.$resized_rel;
            }
        endif;
    }
    elseif(file_exists($dest) && getimagesize($dest)) {
        $img_url="{$up_url}{$dstrel}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
    }
    else {
        $resized=resize_image($img_path,$width,$height,$crop);
        $resized_rel=str_replace($up_dir,'',$resized);
        $img_url=$up_url.$resized_rel;
    }

    if($single) {
        $image = $img_url;
    } else {
        $image = array (
            0 => $img_url,
            1 => $dst_w,
            2 => $dst_h
        );
    }
    return $image;
}
```

В месте, где нужен вывод миниатюры, пишем следующие, изменяя размер миниатюры на нужное вам:

```
<img src="<?php echo aq_resize(first_img(),180,130,true)?>
```

Answer (score 1):

На своих хайлоад проектах использую связку плагинов wp-rocket (полностраничный кеш), memcached (кеш объектов), imagify (компрессия фото) - 2 года, полет нормальный. За это время были перепробованы все кеширующие и компрессионные плагины и только эти три показали себя с лучшей стороны, особенно под нагрузкой

Answer (score 0):

Было бы неплохо собрать все скрипты в один файл, и подключать асинхронно . Так же заминифицировать их и таблицу стилей . Стили тоже подключить асинхронно . Картинки ищите любой сервис по оптимизации.  Гуглится легко . А вобще я использую галп утилиту для этого .  Ну и как сказано выше , кеширование .